# Javascript iterate over derived array

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty shocked I can't find an answer to this (maybe there isn't one).  Suppose I want to iterate over an array one time.  I don't to have to create a variable to iterate with, but it seems that that's what I have to do.  Ideally, I'd be able to do something like this:

```
for (key, val in 'one two three'.split(' ')) {
   console.log(val);
}
```

However, it seems that you can only get the *keys* from javascript's `for..in` syntax.  Is there any way to iterate over that array without storing it to a variable first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

About half of all web surfers (as of this writing, the number's going up all the time) are using browsers that natively support ECMAScript5 (e.g., the 5th edition), which has some new constructs for this, including [`forEach`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18):

```
"one two three".split(" ").forEach(function(val, key) {
    // do stuff here
});
```

(Or if you don't need the `key` variable, just leave it off [e.g., `...forEach(function(val) {...`].)

Even if the browser doesn't have it, `forEach` is one of those features that can be "shimmed" (emulated) entirely correctly even in older browsers, e.g. via es5_shim.js or similar. So just include the shim (or write your own) and happily use it regardless of whether it's natively supported or something you've added. Or you may be using a library that already provides it or an analogue of it (jQuery has `$.each`, Prototype adds `each` to arrays, Backbone offers something similar, etc.).

`forEach` also has the advantage that the loop-specific variables (`entry` and `index`) are contained by the iterator function and so you don't pollute the scope in which you're using it. There is a runtime cost, because you have the function call overhead for every array element. But function calls are very fast in real terms ([even on IE6](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html), which is a dog), you can be sure that whatever else you're doing in the loop body will completely wash out the added overhead.

With the "older" version of JavaScript (3rd edition), there's nothing built in, you either provide your own function for doing it, or on every loop you declare a variable for the array (as well as an indexing variable and an array entry variable), e.g.:

```
var array = "one two three".split(" ");
var key, val;
for (key = 0; key < array.length; ++key) {
    val = array[key];
    // do stuff here
}
```

But again you could provide your own `forEach` easily enough.

Another construct you can use both in older and newer engines is `for..in`, which iterates over the *enumerable properties of an object*. You still end up needing all of the variables, though. Because that means more than just "indexes", you have to add some safeguards:

```
var array = "one two three".split(" ");
var key, val;
for (key in array) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(key) && String(Number(key)) === key) {
        // It's a numeric key and the object itself owns it
        val = array[key];
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

...but in this case it doesn't buy you anything. It's useful for when the array is *sparse* (e.g., has large gaps in it).

Comment: I think "most environments" means something like 4 out of 5 browsers. But does that translate to the same thing as "most deployed environments?"

Comment: It's a normal function that can be implemented in any environment yourself if it is not supplied

Comment: @JAAulde: [Roughly half](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/javascript-answers-using-es5-features-warn-or-not/118023#118023) of the people surfing the web are using browsers that don't have ES5 features yet. **But** this particular feature is readily emulated via es5_shim.js or similar. So you can include the shim (or supply your own), and then happily use it regardless of whether the browser supports it natively or you've added it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder indeed. A good clarification point nonetheless. :)

Comment: "Most environments" usually means "Anything that's not IE".

Comment: @Rocket: In this case, more than just that. :-)

Comment: My main goal here is actually to minimize the amount of javascript code, period.  If I have to do something that runs a little slower on the user's end, it's not a big deal (the array is never going to be that large).  Being able to use `forEach` would be nice, but if IE doesn't have it, no dice .. plus it looks like it would take more characters anyway.  So would defining my own foreach or using a library.  I'm splitting hairs here, but I just want the absolute minimum possible.

Comment: @tandu: If you want the absolute minimum possible, `forEach` (even with a shim) is probably the way to go. The shim needn't be big (~279 characters in es5_shim.min.js, and which you only include it once), and every use will save you typing, particularly if you don't need the `index` for anything. Compare [using `forEach`](http://pastie.org/3355737) vs. [using `for`](http://pastie.org/3355738) with a one-letter index and array variable name. Ignoring the common parts, that's 27 chars for `forEach` vs. 61 for `for`, a savings of 34 chars on every loop. Just 9 loops = overall savings.

Comment: @tandu: Saved characters are not the only thing to consider, though. I added a couple of further notes to the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wholeheartedly agree with you .. in my specific case I only need the loop to run once, so I will have a net savings.  This question is mostly for academic purposes .. I think `forEach` is a great solution.  By the way, it's possible for `for..in` to be shorter if you omit the `var` declaration (technically wrong, but workable): http://pastie.org/3356585 vs. http://pastie.org/3356589

Comment: @tandu: Re omitting `var`: Then you're falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*.

Answer (score 5):

`for/in` is generally not used on arrays as `for` performs the same basic thing with less overhead and no need for a sanity wrapper on the loop block.

That said, given the scenario you present, no, there is no way to obtain the value in such a case. Since `for/in` only lets you get the key, you have to use that key to access the value in a reference to the array.